# How to optimize building a tree from a list of the node paths?

Tags: algorithm, scala, optimization, tree

Suppose I am writing a function `fromPaths(paths: List[String]): Node` to build a tree from a few node paths like this:

```
case class Node(value: String, children: List[Node])
val paths = List("a/b/x", "a/b/y", "a/c", "a/c/d")
fromPaths(paths) // Node("a", List(Node("b", List(Node("x"), Node("y"))), Node("c", List(Node("d")))))
```

I can write a function `addNode(root: Node, path: String): Node` and then just `fold` it over the list. However it looks suboptimal since we traverse the tree from `root` to `node` for each "path" in `paths`.

How would you optimize `fromPaths` for the overall number of traversed nodes ?

Comment: What exactly have you tried, and what is supposed to happen for the input `"a", "a/b/c"`? Should your resulting tree be the same as for `"a", "a/b", "a/b/c"` (no markers on inner nodes?)?

Comment: For `"a", "a/b/c"` the result should be `Node("a", List(Node("b", List(Node("c"))))`.

Comment: I tried some grouping of `paths` by prefix ...

Comment: `List(Node("b"), List(Node("c")))` doesn't even typecheck as anything meaningful?.. And all the `Node` constructors have the wrong arity... Again: should there be no difference between results for `["a/b"]` and `["a", "a/b"]`?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I mean `Node("a", List(Node("b", List(Node("c")))))`

Comment: There should be no difference b/w results of `["a/b"]` and `["a", "a/b"]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious recursion seems to work just fine, at least on your examples:

```
case class Node[A](a: A, children: List[Node[A]])
def trieForest[A](lists: List[List[A]]): List[Node[A]] = {
  lists.filter(_.nonEmpty).groupBy(_.head).map { 
    case (k, vs) =>
    Node(k, trieForest(vs.map(_.tail)))
  }.toList
}

def fromPaths(paths: List[String]): Node[String] = {
  // assumes that there is only one tree in the 
  // top-level forest.
  trieForest(paths.map(_.split("/").toList)).head
}

println(fromPaths(List("a/b/x", "a/b/y", "a/c", "a/c/d")))
```

Prints (up to indentation):

```
Node(a, List(
  Node(b,List(
    Node(y,List()), 
    Node(x,List())
  )),
  Node(c,List(
    Node(d,List())
  ))
))
```

It can't run much faster asymptotically, because you have to look at every part of the input at least once.